# Grammaticality of "a list is added an Item"?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, past-participles, dative-alternation

Using the word *given* as a past participle in the following sentence is, presumably, correct:

> A person is given a gift

Can we use the past participle form of the word *added* in the same way in the following manner?

> A list is added an item

Of course, it is easy to avoid this question and say, "An item was added to the list." But, technically, is the latter form grammatically correct?

Will appreciate elaborate answers and references.

Comment: We do say 'He increased the temperature a small amount', but there's an understood 'by', and this is an example of a measure phrase being used rather than a ditransitive construction. 'She paid him $20.' // We wouldn't use 'a few items' as a measure phrase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not right.

The verb *add* does not take an indirect object the way *give* does.

- You can give a person a present.
- You cannot add ✳a list an item.

That's because *give* is a ditransitive verb (one with two different objects as core syntactic arguments) that allows for [dative
alternation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_shift) with the recipient
in the syntactic slot reserved for the verb's indirect object, which is a core argument to the verb.

In contrast, *add* is not ditransitive; it is monotransitive. With *add*, you are forced to use a prepositional phrase as an optional adjunct
if you want to specify the recipient of the thing added. It is not required, either,
since you can always add items without saying what they're being added *to*. All this
is also true of the verb *append*.

---

You appear to be attempting to make passives with *be* by promoting one
of the two objects to the subject.

1. The gifter is the person who has given someone else this gift.
2. The giftee is the person (who was) given this gift, the person who received it.
3. The gift is the thing (that was) given *to* that recipient.

You will not be able to do all that in the same manner when adding things *to* lists.

1. The adder is the person who has added an item *to* a list.
2. The addend is the item (that was) added *to* a list.
3. The list is the thing (that) someone added an item *to*.